# Query Pattern for ORs in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We understand that it is not possible to do ORs in Cloud Datastore.  Has anyone any suggested patterns for a workaround for this particular query requirement:

Users have a list of tags that represent their access control.  Groups also have a list of tags that represent their membership.  We want to run a query essentially that gets all the Groups a User has access to, similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM Group where tags IN ("administrator", "super_user")
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Group where tags.administrator = true OR tags.super_user = true
```

Is there any way to model this particular access pattern? We understand that we can do this at the application level by merging queries, but these resultsets are large and we don't want to start sorting at the application level.

If we can't do this any way then is there a better way to model our entities in Datastore to make this kind of query possible?

Comment: Are you considering `query = Group.query(Group.tags.IN(['administrator', 'super_user']))` expensive / inefficient? If so - do you have multiple values for `tags`? If it's just the two - you could have two indexed properties `is_administrator` & `is_super_user` and query by them. Otherwise - you could also create a separate model containing the relationships between memberships / groups & users...

Comment: We are using Cloud Datastore not AppEngine, so don't have access to IN. Also - does IN support sorting? Tags are user specific, so we don't know what they are going to be ahead of time. The separate model is hard to maintain - Users and Groups was an example. We might have millions of 'Groups' and maintaining a relationship model would be slow. Also because we can't join we still can't do any cursor based pagination as we need to issue multiple queries...